# .NET regex not matching with negative assertion

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a file in which I need to match strings of the form `DEFAULT_DATABASE = [db_name]` only if the `db_name` is **not** `master`.
I'm using the following regex:

`DEFAULT_DATABASE\s*=\s*\[(?!master)\]`

but the negative assertion doesn't match. There are 0 matches no matter what `db_name`. What am I doing wrong? Here's my test code:

```
var inputs = new string [] {
    "some text DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master] more [more] text",
    "some text DEFAULT_DATABASE = [masters] more [more] text",
    "some text DEFAULT_DATABASE = [abc] more [more] text"
};

var re = new Regex(@"DEFAULT_DATABASE\s*=\s*\[(?!master)\]");

foreach (var input in inputs) {
    if (re.IsMatch(input)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Match: {input}, value: {re.Match(input).Value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the reflex should be like DEFAULT_DATABASE\s*=\s*\[(?!master)(\w)+\] or whatever suits to match “not [master]” part

Comment: You're right! Makes sense. Please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The regex that works to my requirements is actually pretty awkward: `DEFAULT_DATABASE\s*=\s*\[(?!master\]).+?\]`

Comment: What you want is probably this: `DEFAULT_DATABASE\s*=\s*(?!master)\w+`

Comment: I’d be careful with closing square bracket. Afaik .+? Will match as much as possible - till the last square bracket in the input.

Comment: I need also to match if "master" is just a prefix - e.g. "masters", "masteraaa" but not "master", hence this closing bracket. It works :)

Comment: Sorry I’m from mobile phone. It’s a bit awkward to test regex properly before posting an answer with it

Comment: Yes, but when it actually matches .+ most likely will go mad and match everything till the very last closing square bracket that will go for \\]

Comment: I just thought the same, then checked and updated my code example - and it's still okay :)

Comment: @Endrju can you edit with more example of input and add for each one if it is a match or not? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to include the closing bracket in the negative assertion and then allow for valid text before the closing bracket:

```
    var re = new Regex(@"DEFAULT_DATABASE\s*=\s*\[(?!master\]).*?\]");
```

Edit: The pattern must be non-greedy.

Comment: Perfect! Although not intuitive at all :) Thank you. With one minor correction - the pattern must be non-greedy, so I'm editing the answer.

Comment: `Perfect! Although not intuitive at all :) ` You just describe the whole regex world \o/ Maybe a basic Linq solution is what you should use...

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a basic Linq? Maybe I missed something...
What about something like this:

```
var inputs = new string[]{
    "some text DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master] more text"
    , "some text DEFAULT_DATABASE = [masters] more text"
    , "some text DEFAULT_DATABASE = [abc] more text"};

var matchs = inputs
    .Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf("DEFAULT_DATABASE = ["))) // trim start
    .Select(x => x.Remove(x.IndexOf("]") + 1)) // trim end
    .Where(x => !x.Contains("[master]"));

foreach (var input in matchs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Match: {input}");
}
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VpR4Tc)

Comment: Thanks! As a performance freak, and knowing that plain text search is usually much faster than regex, I'd surely use this method in real app, should the problem be as formulated in the question. This time, however, it was just a Find&Replace regex that was needed, and after first failed attempt my curiosity has woken up and I started digging. After many years of working with regexes it was the first time it's beaten me.